# How to get values from user using comma in c#?

Tags: c#

```
using System;


namespace reverse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] a = new int [10];
            for (int i= 0; i<a.Length; i++)
            {
                a[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here I can get values from a user by pressing enter key after each time i give the value but I want to give value as a whole with comma. Thanks!

Comment: Look at string.Split

Comment: you should take that value within a string not within an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to gradually step towards *functional programming*.

**Why?**

Weel, with words from Eric Lippert from "[Functional programming](https://ericlippert.com/2016/01/11/functional-programming-for-beginners/) for **beginners**"

> I will talk about the “why” a little bit, but basically it boils down to

1. a great many bugs are caused by bad mutations.

> By taking a page
>       from functional style and designing programs so that variables and
>       data structures change as little as possible, we can eliminate a
>       large source of bugs.

2. Structuring programs into small functions
   whose outputs each depend solely on inputs

> makes for programs that
>       are easy to unit test.

3. the ability to pass functions as data

> allows us to create new and interesting control flows and patterns,
>   like LINQ.

### Rewriting your code

Use Linq in a single and **simple** line:

```
    int [] res =
         Console.ReadLine () // read the input
         .Split (',') // transform it into an array
         .Take (10) // consider only the first 10 strings
         .Select (int.Parse) // transform them into int
         .ToArray (); // and finally get an array
```

You can add a check  after the Split and before Take:

```
.Where (d => {int t; return int.TryParse (d, out t);}).Take
```

Comment: You can just do `Select(int.Parse)` instead of `Select(x => int.Parse(x))`

Comment: Now with this check it should be marked as an answer. Simple and quick solution.

Comment: @m.rogalski this is clearly a question from beginner. He should first learn how to solve these kinds of problems with just variables, loops and if statements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and read comments to get more info :

```
static void Main()
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine(); // grab user input in one whole line
    string[] splitted = input.Split(','); // split user input by comma sign ( , )
    int[] a = new int[splitted.Length]; // create a new array that matches user input values length
    for(int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++) // iterate through all user input values
    {
        int temp = -1; // create temporary field to hold result 
        int.TryParse(splitted[i], out temp); // check if user inpu value can be parsed into int
        a[i] = temp; // assign parsed int value
    }
}
```

This method will ensure that program will execute even if user wont input numerics. For example if user input will be :

```
1 , 2,3,45,8,9898
```

The output will be :

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 45, 8, 9898 }
```

But if the input will be :

```
1,adsadsa,13,4,6,dsd
```

The output will be :

```
{ 1, 0, 13, 4, 6, 0 }
```

Comment: Worked like charm! I made some modification for myself. But instead of using int as a data type if we use string as common it will accept anything, will this affect performance in long run?

Comment: The final part of your answer is wrong. You don't get -1 in the result if the input is not a valid number but 0. Int32.TryParse set the default value for integers (0) if there is no conversion. It doesn't preserve the actual value of the variable. The _out_ specifier requires the method to set a value for that parameter before returning